# Need help understanding C# float string formatting

Tags: c#

In a nutshell, I'm wondering why the ToString() lines below don't match my expectations.

```
float actual = 111253.469F;
double rounded = Math.Round(actual, 2); //  111253.47 (expected)
string stringified = actual.ToString(); //  111253.50 (expected 111253.469)
string currency = actual.ToString("C"); // $111253.50 (expected 111253.47 or possibly .46)
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Note:
I don't expect the floating point value to be exact, per the other questions on floating point numbers. However I do expect the string output to reflect the string value of the floating point number in question.

In this case, if I set a break point and look at the value of 'actual' in a quick watch, it doesn't display '111253.5', it displays '111253.469'. I don't understand why that wouldn't be the case when printing as well. And especially in the currency case, I would expect it to round to the appropriate decimal point and then display, rather than picking some other literal value. This isn't a math question, it is a ToString() behavior question.

Edit:
Per Quantic's comment below, it appears the `ToString` is using the `G` format by default which limits the number to 7 significant digits, resulting in the number being seen here.

Comment: Impossible. 111253 will never give 11253 as output

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry, my commented lines were inexact (left out the first 1), but it is the decimal piece that is throwing me, sorry. I'll correct.

Comment: If you want two numbers on decimal piece you can use these samples: ToString("0.00"); 
ToString("n2"); // for number

ToString("c2"); // for currency

Comment: [`float.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5dbkt9x(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the "G" modifier by default, and the [`G Modifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString) uses 7 digit precision for a single aka float. This is because, [A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @utaco Using any of those formats also results in the '.50' value, as opposed to the expected.

Comment: @Quantic thank you, that does clarify the default 'ToString()' operation.  Still a little confused by the currency behavior, per edit.

Comment: sorry my fault. check this. string stringified = actual.ToString("R");

Comment: Just as a comment, this is all much much easier if you store the currency as an integer where 1 unit = 1 smallest unit in that currency (eg $100.52 = 10052)

Comment: `float` only has 7 digits of precision, so the only one that surprises me is the `Math.Round` result.  I'd expect it to have an input value of `111253.50`, which would still be `111253.50` after rounding,.  I wonder if the compiler in inlining the scalar value into the IL.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, I actually don't know why I can declare this which is obviously more than 7 digits: `float actual = 11122342342342342342323534232344234234.42342234234234234234234423234423342369F;`, I think this "decimal representation of a binary floating point number" is converted to the nearest 7 digit precision "binary floating point" exponential number which is `1.11223423E+37`. *shrug*, I do wonder *how* it does that conversion though.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you use `float actual = float.Parse("111253.469");`?

Comment: @DStanley: yeah, that's a little weird. Playing around in dotnetfiddle and looking at the generated il, you can see it loads `111253.67` as a float with `ldc.r4` and then converts it to a double with `conv.r8` before calling `System.Math.Round`

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN about Single.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f71z6k0c(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> By default, the **return value only contains 7 digits of precision** although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally. If the value of this instance has greater than 7 digits, M:System.Single.ToString(System.String) returns P:System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.PositiveInfinitySymbol or P:System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the expected number. **If you require more precision, specify format with the "G9" format specification, which always returns 9 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 7 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 9 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision**.

So your code example behaves exactly as documented:

- `ToString()` will use `"G"` by default, which will use 7 digits precision
- `ToString("C")` will also use 7 digits of precision

Both `"R"` and `"G9"` will return `111253.469`, `"G8"` returns `111253.47`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a **ToString()** issue, you have a **float** issue.

A `float` is a floating-point value that by definition has a 7-digit precision: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

Now, you have more than 7 digits: `float actual = 111253.469F`, so the system rounds least significant ones and you get **111253.5** as a result of your operations. 
Notice that **double** is calculated correctly, as it can handle more than 7 significant digits.